# Use array expression from subquery in ANY() condition

Tags: postgresql, subquery, syntax

I have a relatively complicated query with a subquery fetching an array like so:

```
...
ARRAY(SELECT category_id FROM category_schedule_con con
      WHERE s.id = con.schedule_id ORDER BY category_id) AS cats,
...
```

and would like to use the array 'cats' in a later WHERE condition like

```
...
WHERE 4 = ANY(cats)
...
```

But this does not work as it states that the column 'cats' doesn't exist.
c/p'ing the subquery into the `ANY` clause yields the expected result.

Comment: Your version of Postgres is missing. Also, it's almost always better to post a complete (simplified) query, and the table definitions are almost always helpful, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Explanation

By definition in the **SQL standard** (which Postgres implements) you can reference output columns in `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY`, but ***not*** in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-SELECT-LIST):

> An output column's name can be used to refer to the column's value in
>   `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` clauses, but not in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clauses;
>   there you must write out the expression instead.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL reusing computation result in select query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11218453/939860)
- [PostgreSQL Where count condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8119815/939860)
- [GROUP BY + CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19849537/939860)

Obviously, your subquery is a *correlated subquery* expression in the **`SELECT` list** (which is hidden in the question due to over-simplification).

To avoid repeating lengthy / expensive expressions in the `WHERE` clause you can use a subquery in the **`FROM` list**. A correlated subquery in the `SELECT` list ***cannot*** be referenced by alias in the `WHERE` clause, that's just an output column like any other.

Chances are, your query can be *much* more efficient ...

### Better query

Applying the above, this query would work:

```
SELECT s.*, con.cats
FROM   some_table s  -- guessing the missing query
JOIN  (
   SELECT schedule_id
        , array_agg(category_id ORDER BY category_id) AS cats
   FROM   category_schedule_con
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) con ON con.schedule_id = s.id
WHERE  3 = ANY(cats);
```

*Now* you can reference the column alias `cats` in the `WHERE` clause. But this query is **terribly inefficient** for big tables for multiple reasons. Most importantly, the predicate is not [sargable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable).

Using `GROUP BY` and [the aggregate function `array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) instead of the [`ARRAY` constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) because we are producing *multiple* arrays in a single query.

You can apply an `ORDER BY` clause to almost any aggregate function, but a **sorted subquery** typically performs better:

```
SELECT s.*, con.cats
FROM   some_table s
JOIN  (
   SELECT id, array_agg(category_id) AS cats
   FROM   (
      SELECT schedule_id AS id, category_id  -- alias id for convenience
      FROM   category_schedule_con
      ORDER  BY 1, 2  -- to get ordered list per schedule_id
      ) con
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) con USING (id)
WHERE  3 = ANY(cats);
```

More importantly, pull the predicate (the `WHERE` condition) down into the subquery to make it possible to use an **index** and **exclude irrelevant rows early**. Much faster with big tables:

```
SELECT s.*, con.cats
FROM   some_table s
JOIN  (
   SELECT id, array_agg(category_id) AS cats
   FROM  (
      SELECT schedule_id AS id, category_id
      FROM   category_schedule_con c
      WHERE  EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM category_schedule_con
         WHERE  schedule_id = c.schedule_id
         AND    category_id = 3
         )
      ORDER  BY 1, 2
      ) con
   GROUP BY 1
   ) con USING (id);
```

Depending on data distribution, a `LATERAL` join (requires Postgres 9.3+) may be more efficient:

```
SELECT s.*, con.cats
FROM   some_table s
     , LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT category_id
      FROM   category_schedule_con
      WHERE  schedule_id = s.id
      ORDER  BY 1
      ) AS cats
   ) con
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM category_schedule_con
   WHERE  schedule_id = s.id
   AND    category_id = 3
   );
```

About `LATERAL`:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

But it should be the ***fastest*** to *invert* the logic: start by finding `schedule_id` that have `category_id = 3`, self-join to `category_schedule_con` and aggregate before joining to the other table:

```
SELECT s.*, con.cats
FROM  (
   SELECT id, array_agg(c.category_id) AS cats
   FROM  (
      SELECT schedule_id AS id
      FROM   category_schedule_con
      WHERE  category_id = 3
      ) x
   JOIN   category_schedule_con c USING (id)
   GROUP  BY id
   ) con
JOIN  some_table s USING (id);
```

### Index

Be sure to have a multicolumn index like:

```
CREATE INDEX category_schedule_con_foo_idx ON category_schedule_con
(schedule_id, category_id);
```

For the last query, we'd need the *inverted* sequence of columns:

```
CREATE INDEX category_schedule_con_bar_idx ON category_schedule_con
(category_id, schedule_id);
```

and another one with two columns switched back again. Two indexes on just `(category_id)` and `(schedule_id)` would work fast, too;

A PK or UNIQUE constraint on both columns serves as well.

Answer (score 1):

Preamble: Check out [Erwin's](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3684/erwin-brandstetter) answer on this for a really interesting and detailed explanation.

I think one way to get this to work appropriately is to name the subquery via a CTE, like

```
WITH cats AS(SELECT category_id FROM category_schedule_con con 
     WHERE s.id = con.schedule_id ORDER BY category_id)...
```

and then later when you need to apply your `WHERE` predicate, use

```
... WHERE 4 = ANY(ARRAY(SELECT * FROM cats)) ...
```

Give that a shot and see if it works for you.

***Note***: you can also write the predicate `WHERE` clause as

```
... WHERE 4 = ANY(SELECT * FROM cats) ...
```

and the query should still work, but may yield a different query plan, as the planner treats sets of records and arrays differently. If you are running into query run time issues, this could create a 'hack' fix to your problem.

Comment: I may be wrong but I thought the OP meant that they want to reference `cats` in the WHERE clause of the same SELECT statement (on the same level). And you probably know that you can't reference a column alias in a WHERE clause.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right.  I think I misunderstood the OP, and I fumbled my repsonse a bit. In my defense, I was trying to write the response at the end of a long work day.  Not in my defense, I shouldn't have been so hasty! :P  Either way, I have made an edit to reflect this, where simply using a CTE could be a fix.

Comment: Looking at it again, I'm actually still not sure I know what the OP is asking for...  I thought they were trying to build the `cats` result as a single column set of returned records, to later be referenced as a table (or an array, if applying the `ARRAY()` condition).  If they're trying to build it as a column, then I'm off base, but I don't think I know enough about their query.